# How do I make dig use a source IP other than localhost while querying a DNS server running locally on my machine?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dig

I am trying to run a coredns plugin https://github.com/coredns/demo that returns 1.1.1.1 for 172.0.0.0/8 or 127.0.0.0/8 and 8.8.8.8 for everything else.

I run the binary and try to make a request from dig using `dig example.org @localhost -p1053 +short` which returns 1.1.1.1 since the request is sent from localhost

Is there anyway I can send a request from dig to coredns that it might look like to the DNS server that it is sent from another IP and it will return 8.8.8.8 instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From dig manual:

```
   -b address[#port]
       Set the source IP address of the query. The address must be a valid address on one of the host's network interfaces, or "0.0.0.0" or "::". An optional port may be
       specified by appending "#<port>"
```

Otherwise, if the server supports ECS (EDNS Client Subnet) you can use dig option `+subnet=addr` to give it to the server and see how its reply changes.